# What is the "wine of their transitory powers"?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> They sit, filled with the wine of their transitory powers, aloof from
> the fatigues and dangers of conflict, pulling imaginary strings in
> people's minds.

*- The new world order by H.G. Wells*

what does the author try to express by "sitting, filled with wine"?

Answer (score 2):

"Filled with wine" is a slightly old-fashioned way of saying *drunk* (to mean inebriated, or intoxicated).

It is often said that *power* is "intoxicating" - that it is alluring, and also dulls the senses to certain other feelings. That idea is being stretched out here by saying that they were "drunk" on their power, and they felt no sense of danger.